# Analysing categorical variables across several categories (LogLinear analysis?)

Tags: r, categorical-data, log-linear, multinomial-logit

I'm editing this question in hopes of improving it, and thus receiving some advice on it.

I have collected info on diet from several populations. There are different groups (e.g. ElMolo) made of individuals and each individual eats different foods (e.g. cheese). Each food has a specific weight (g) (dependent variable) Also, each food is classified to a category (e.g cheese is animal).

Goal: I want to know if the proportion of each food category (e.g. animal) changes significantly accross populations (e.g. Webuye). For instance, do ElMolo eat *proportionaly* more animal foods than the other populations?

Below is a graph to illustrate my results:
[image]

Questions:

1. I believe I should not do an ANOVA on the frequencies, but instead do a loglinear analysis using a contingency table. Is this correct?
2. Before applying loglinear analysis, I need to build a contingency table.  I tried this:

   ```
   ContingencyTable2<-xtabs(Weight~Food+Tribe, data=AllDiet)
   ```

However my data is raw: so Weight is weight of food in g per individual (i.e the data is not in frequency). [Here](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html) it says that "If a variable is included on the left side of the formula, it is assumed to be a vector of frequencies (useful if the data have already been tabulated)." So do I need to calculate the frequencies before building the contingency table or is there another way to do this?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Be aware that questions about how to use R are generally off topic here. You may not get an answer to #2.

Comment: That's fine. #1 is more important. Thank you for the warning

Comment: Sure, just letting you know. What is the relationship between `Freq` & `Weight`?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply: Weight=Freq *Meal Weight; However I'd like to analyse Freq only